# Href turning into data-href

Tags: reactjs, fonts, next.js, href, google-webfonts

So I have this weird problem in my Next JS app, I imported google fonts as shown below

```
<link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@300;400;500&family=Source+Serif+Pro:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
rel="stylesheet"
    
/>
```

and instead of **href** in my browser it shows **data-href**="...", so problem is that google doesn't recognize this as link

can someone explain why is this happening and, is there a way to block this from happening?

Comment: Almost certainly not without a [mcve], honestly.

Comment: How and where are you adding that `link` tag in your code?

Comment: So in NextJS app I added google fonts in pages/document.js ,
where you have simple structure , 

 <Html> 
 <Head>   
 <link google fonts added>
 </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>                                                                                                                the problem  is  when you add href it should be href this is simple html, and somehow it turns in data-href

Comment: `<Html> 
 <Head>   
 <link google fonst added>
 </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
  </Html>`

Answer (score 4):

This is because Next introduced [Font Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization):

> By default, Next.js will automatically inline font CSS at build time, eliminating an extra round trip to fetch font declarations.

So, it modified `href` to be `data-href` because it no longer needs `href` since it won't be making that request on the client.  I'm not sure why it needs `data-href` at all, I would think it could just throw away the URL after building.

Comment: To turn off font optimization, you can make `optimizeFonts: false` in the config options in next.config.js.